# LINQ AND OR logic

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of items, which belong to a group. So I could have Group 1 and 2. In group 1 might be item 1,2,3 and 4 and in group 2 are items 5 and 6.

I then take a list of objects that belong to those items (so at the minute, the logic says fetch me all objects that belong to items 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6).

How would I write a LINQ query that basically says:

Fetch me all objects that belong to either items 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 **AND** 5 or 6?

Sounds a little odd, but its for a filtering system so a user could say something like; I want to see all people based in Oregon or California who are of the type candidate or interviewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building the conditions dynamically I recommend [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). It provides a fluent syntax that makes it easy to build up filters without manual `ExpressionTree` manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.Where(x => (x.based == "Oregon" || x.based == "California") && (x.type == "candidate" || x.type == "interviewer"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm building it up dynamically, so I'm given a list of filter items grouped into groups and then building the filter.

Comment: @Paul: can you show what interface your filter "group of group" has?

Comment: he wants to build large queries with conditions that can be broken up into small queries.